# Laptop monitor as a server's display

Tags: display, monitors

I have connected my server through displayport-VGA cabel to my laptop but my Ubuntu 14 on laptop recognizes it as a view destination, not a view source.

How can I revert it and get view from a server displayed on a laptop monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you used a Male-Male VGA cable to connect one video output port to another video output port?  Working as expected, I'm afraid.

This is basically a much less dangerous version of expecting everything to be fine when connecting a (deliberately-very-hard-to-find) Male-Male power cord between two outlets.

You need to connect an *output* to an *input*.

Comment: yes, indeed I've used male displayport-male VGA. do not have much experience with hardware and I thought it's working both ways... so which ports can be used in laptop as an input display?

Comment: Generally, laptops do not support this behavior.  You will need to get a display which has video _input_ ports to which the server can be connected.  Think of it this way:  You have a PlayStation 4 and an XBox One.  You connect an HDMI cable between the two.  Where do you expect to be able to see the video output of one or the other?

Comment: I thought the signal is bidirectional and just handled by software. like in usb - when you stick it into the drive - you can send data to it or from it

Comment: The physical port (in the case of DisplayPort) is cable of bidirectional communication (D-sub AKA VGA is not), but the hardware behind the port also has to be designed to expect that sort of use-case.  USB is bidirectional, but you can plug two USB printers into each other to no practical effect.